# OpenCV error: ‘MAT’ is not a member of ‘cv’

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am attempting to execute a simple OpenCV program, but receive the following: `error: ‘MAT’ is not a member of ‘cv’`. I installed OpenCV from source following the instructions on the [docs page](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html). I then simplified the tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html) to minimize potential problems. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Read in image
    cv::MAT im1;
    im1 = cv::imread("opencv-logo.png");
    printf("Done\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project ( pleasework )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( pleasework pleasework.cpp )
target_link_libraries( pleasework ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

What puzzles me is that `cv::MAT` throws and error but `cv::imread` is just fine. I peeked inside CMakeCache.txt, and cmake appears to find OpenCV fine.

```
//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.
OpenCV_DIR:PATH=/home/vector/opt/share/OpenCV
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: C++ is case sensitive. It's `cv::Mat`

Comment: Well, that was silly of me. You are exactly right. Changed to `Mat` and we are all good. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must change `cv::MAT` to `cv::Mat`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Read in image
    cv::Mat im1;
    im1 = cv::imread("opencv-logo.png");
    printf("Done\n");

    return(0);
}
```